# fortran 77 direct access max record number

Tags: fortran

I'm trying to store double precision data from different blocks into a direct access file, i.e. the data is g(m,n) for one block and they all have the same size. Here's the code I wrote:

```
OPEN(3,FILE='a.TMP',ACCESS='DIRECT',RECL=8*m*n)

WRITE(3,REC=I) ((g(K,L),K=1,m),L=1,n) ! here "I" is the block number
```

I have 200 this kind of blocks. However, I got the following error after writing the 157th block data into the file:

`severe (66): output statement overflows record, unit 3`

I believe that means the record size is too large.
Is there any way to handle this? I wonder if there is the record number has a maximum value.

Comment: There must be a maximum record number, but it will be larger than 157. How big are `m` and `n`?  What is the implied file size of writing 157 records of length `8*m*n`?  The error message suggests that the output is too longer for the record, which is peculiar if you are using the same write statement for all of the records without any change in `m` and `n`.  Is there any way these could have been altered?  Did you successfully write some records before the 157th?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The m and n are not very big. In my case, m=30, n=4. Since m and n are defined outside of the loop, I wouldn't think they altered. I'm not sure how to track if it was written successfully before the 157th since it is a binary file.(is there any way to check that?) What I did is to print the block number before this write record statement. And after printing the 157th block, the error occurred.

Comment: If you print the block number before the write statement you show, did you get block numbers printed before the value 157 for which the error occurred?

Comment: Yes, I did get the block numbers printed before the 157th block. And as I didn't get any error before that line, I was assuming the first 156 blocks of data was written properly into the file.

Comment: Standard advice: turn on full warning and error checking options of your compiler.  What compiler are you using?  Without seeing more of the code, I don't have other suggestions.

Comment: I found if the block data were not changed in the loop after their initialization, the code works fine. So there much be some length change when updating the data itself rather than the max record number. I'll update when I find the cause.